# yii2 unknown property error

Tags: php, yii2

ссылки на файлы:
 [News](https://gist.github.com/4t4nner/56172a4e03ae0102892b0928e31e34a0) [NewsSearch](https://gist.github.com/4t4nner/8256b02d4d70d5e662a5224cd9098f95) [composer.json](https://gist.github.com/4t4nner/e7df9b13d3263606ab6caeed3cd3c202) [Validator](https://gist.github.com/4t4nner/850098975b8ec5e796887c4122959f81)

Можете объяснить, почему при проверке одних свойств ошибка возникает, при других - нет?

при вызове валидатора в NewsSearch.php:53 с моделью в которой нет свойств возникает ошибка

```
Unknown Property – yii\base\UnknownPropertyException
Getting unknown property: common\modules\news\models\NewsSearch::created_by
```

**Поведение**:

```
NewsSearch:53 -> Validator:344 -> Validator:248 -> Validator:463
```

в `validateAttributes`, `$model->$attribute` может быть не задан, тогда в некоторых случаях передается как `null`, в других выбрасывается исключение

**Проблема**:
в модели нет ни одного свойства, и, соответственно, на

```
$this->isEmpty($model->$attribute)
```

выбрасывается исключение, т.к. такого свойства нет. Вот только на атрибутах `$id` и `$category_id` исключение не выбрасывается. **Почему**?

**Примечание**

Стоит описать эти свойства в News.php:39, ошибка больше не возникает (т.к. свойство есть и оно `null`).

Даже если я описывал их как `int` в phpDoc, ошибка всё равно оставалась. Значит, свойства из phpDoc не берутся. Но почему `$id` и `$category_id` заходят в isEmpty как `null` и **не вызывает исключения**?

Comment: Попробуй вместо $model->$attribute  $model->attribute. То есть attribute без $

Comment: Это не кастомный код, а с фреймворка (`\yii\validators\Validator`). Меня волнует не как исправить код фреймворка , а почему он в одних случаях работает, в других - нет